# The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I am using npgsql + EF6 but i am getting following error after performing Insert operation on table

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context.
> The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message:
> Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'user'
> have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration.
> Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.

```
foreach (string code in customer)
{
    user us = new user();
    us = new user { code = code, user_id = user_id, roleid = roleid};

    _context.user.Add(us);
    _context.Entry(us).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.
}

_context.SaveChanges();
```

After checking the database, I find that the values are indeed updated in the database, though there is a issue while refreshing the context.

Here is the class generated through DB model:

```
public partial class user
{
    public double id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> user_id { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> roleid { get; set; }
    public virtual roles roles { get; set; }
}
```

Here id is the primary key and is auto incremented through a trigger in the database.

Comment: I think the exception is clear enough to understand what the problem is? Use `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption` for primary key field

Comment: Don't add anything to db before checking if id already there, if it is then this is a update not an add

Comment: @JohnPeters as i said the values are added in DB and were not there beforehand hence i dont think model should have issues refreshing with it , or am i wrong in that ?

Comment: Can you try first? Obviously something is not right.